# How to create speckles in a sponge surface

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

How to achieve this shiny effect on the sponge surface in Cycles?
The sponge shows tiny speckles reflecting light.

[image: Sponge]

Comment: What you've tried so far? Can you provide a sponge to test?

Comment: I have tried hair particles with roughness but not working.

Comment: I'd say this is the opposite of shiny, or are you talking about the few very bright spots on the bottom of the image ?

Comment: Yes, how to get that spots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this simple node setup :
[image]

First add a Noise Texture and set its Scale pretty high. Use a Bright/Contrast to emphasis the effect, you should get something like that :
[image]

Add an RGB Curve to gain more control. The right of the curve will control the roughness of the tiny spots : I set it to 0.0 so they will be really shiny. The left of the curve will control the roughness of the base material ; If you set it to 1.0, it will be totally diffuse ; I recommend some intermediate value, around 0.75 or higher, but it's your move.
[image]

Finally, connect this into the Roughness slot of a principled BSDF and tweak the other values to fit your needs (some Transmission should look good, maybe even some Subsurface). Once it's done, you'll probably want to adjust the RGB Curve a bit.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making the Brillo pad out of a refractive material, then displacing it with a high-scale noise texture using a Displacement node: this would be very close to what the pad is like in real life.